# When 'allow_singular is False', the input matrix must be symmetric positive definite

Tags: python, imputation

Im trying to use autoimpute for a dataset Im using.

I am trying to use the MultipleImputer from autoimpute,
and use the pmm strategy.

My dataframe consists of 20+ columns with int, float values.

However as the dataset is being imputed the error

```
When 'allow_singular is False', the input matrix must be symmetric positive definite.
```

is shown and the kernel stops.

```py
mi = MultipleImputer(strategy='pmm', return_list=True)
mi_data = mi.fit_transform(imp_df)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.